# Show weak* convergence in dual space X'

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, cauchy-sequences, weak-convergence

The problem goes as:

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $(f_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}$ be a weak$^*$ Cauchy sequence in $X$, that is, $(f_n(x))^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is a Cauchy sequence $\forall x \in X$. Show that $(f_n)^{\infty}_{n=1}$ is weak$^*$ convergent in $X'$ (dual space of $X$).

My idea was to find a proper weak$^*$  limit and then apply the Banach-Steinhaus theorem to conclude that $(f_n)^{\infty}_{n=1} \xrightarrow{w^*} f \in X'$. But I haven't been able to accomplish this.

Appreciating all help.

Comment: You are on the right track, observe that for fixed $x$, the sequence $(f_n(x))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is convergent on $\mathbb{R}$. Can you define the desired $f$ now?

Comment: @dem0nakos I have showed that $f$ is linear, but I don't know how to use the Banach-Steinhaus theorem to conclude that $f \in X'$.

Comment: @aaa $\sup_{\Vert x\Vert\leq 1}|f(x)|\leq\sup_{\Vert x\Vert\leq 1,n\in\mathbb{N}}|f_n(x)|$, and the right-most sup is finite by B-S